# CardView border style

Tags: android, styles, border, android-cardview

I have a problem in my app
when I display a CardView (android 4) I can't fit in the layout. It is like i have a padding of 1dp or something like that. In android 5 the CardView fit perfectly, so I don't know what is the problem. Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668635/unnecessary-padding-in-cardview?rq=1

Comment: @Priya Hi checked and that's not my problem. I think know that my problem is the recyclerview. The cardview fits nice but when i put the cards in the recyclerview i have a padding of one dp. (if i set the background blue in my recyclerview I can see a border blue arround my cards) but i have no margin or padding

Comment: If it is inside recycler view check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995236/cardview-inside-recyclerview-has-extra-margins?rq=1

Comment: @Priya Than you for your help, I used a negative padding of 1dp and It works!