# How to remove the gray margin in the cardviews in a gridlayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using a gridlayout and when I add the cardviews there's a gray margin covering the sides. Is there any way I can remove/hide it? I'm still exploring android studio.

[image]

Comment: Please show code of Layout contains CardView and the one that contains RecyclerView

Comment: `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Answer (score 1):

Already answered on these links

[CardView inside RecyclerView has extra margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995236/cardview-inside-recyclerview-has-extra-margins)

[Unnecessary padding in CardView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668635/unnecessary-padding-in-cardview)

```
useCompatPadding=true
```